# Virtual Machine Monitoring tool

Tags: performance, virtual-machine

I want to monitor performance of virtual machine in terms of memory utilization,CPU usage etc.I need an OpenSource tool that monitors the performance of  virtual machine,have good Application Programming Interface and have an alerting system.Which tool is suitable here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this tool VMturbo. Otherwise you can look at Nagios

http://vmturbo.com/vhm-earth-why-pay-for-monitoring/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=banner-ad&utm_campaign=vhm-earth&utm_content=728x90top&utm_term=tagset1

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple, drop-in, open-source monitoring tool and you can install it on each virtual machine, you could try [glances](http://nicolargo.github.io/glances/) and eventually aggregate the metrics in one of the [supported gateway](https://github.com/nicolargo/glances/blob/master/docs/glances-doc.rst#gateway-to-others-services) (influxdb, Grafana, Statsd, Graphite, ...).